# What do i input in the Matrix element constructor to fill the matrix?

Tags: javascript

```
    export class Matrix {

    constructor(...m) {
        console.log(...m);
        this.m = new Array(16).fill(0).splice(0, m.length, ...m);
    }

    toArray() {
        return [...this.m];
    }

    toString() {
        return `(${this.m.join(',')})`;
    }
    negate(){

    }
}
const mtrx = new Matrix(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
```

This is the constructor my teacher gave me, how can I call this constructor and put elements inside? ...m means any array but I cant find the right syntax online. If i call it how i did i get a matrix full of 0.

Comment: `...m` as a parameter means any number of arguments which will be available as an array in the body of the function. see: [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) – perhaps you can figure the rest from there.

Comment: const mtrx = new Matrix(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16); when i call it like this i get a matrix full of 0 and not my numbers

Comment: Yes, chaining `splice()` directly on the `new Array` assigns the return value of `splice()` to `this.m` and since `splice()` returns the deleted items you end up with the original array of zeros assigned. The simplest fix is to use a [Grouping operator ( )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) to first assign the new Array to `this.m` then splicing. `(this.m = new Array(16).fill(0)).splice(0, m.length, m);` This disregards the return value of `splice()` and simply mutates the array in place.

Answer (score 0):

What worked is just simply doing this:

```
this.m = new Array(16).fill(0);
this.m.splice(0, m.length, ...m);
```